# How to filter out rows that have same number for all columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to filter out the rows in a data frame that have same data across all columns in the same row? In this example, I want to identify `user_id` `1` and `3`. How do I do that?

```
df <- read_csv("user_id, q1, q2, q3, q4
1, 5, 5, 5, 5
2, 4, 3, 5 ,6
3, 2, 2, 2, 2
4, 5, 4, NA, 4")
```

Purpose: To identify people who tick the same boxes all questions in questionnaires.

Update: The suggested solution works fine till q1 has NA.

```
df <- read_csv("user_id, q1, q2, q3, q4
               1, 5, 5, 5, 5
               2, NA, 3, 5 ,6
               3, 2, 2, 2, 2
               4, 5, 4, NA, 4")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick one of the questions, `q1` for instance, and compare it with other questions, select if all the questions are equal;

```
df$user_id[rowSums(df$q1 != df[-1], na.rm=T) == 0]
# [1] 1 3
```

---

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(.[-1] != q1, na.rm=T) == 0)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  user_id    q1    q2    q3    q4
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1       1     5     5     5     5
#2       3     2     2     2     2
```

- Compare `q1` column with other `q`s columns with `.[-1] != q1`, here `.` is `df` piped from `%>%`, `.[-1]` drops the `user_id` column;
- Check how many columns are not equal to `q1` by doing `rowSums(.[-1] != q1, na.rm=T)` ignoring NAs;
- If non of the columns are not equal `q1`, then all the `q`s columns have the same number, filter based on it;

Comment: Many thanks, Psidom. Looks like the 2nd approach is what I need. Could you explain the code a bit more please? I'm very new to R.

Comment: Updated with some explanations ~

Comment: @Tyn, you can use the first one as well if you just do `df[rowSums(df$q1 != df[-1], na.rm=T) == 0,]`

Comment: The solution has slight problem when q1 is NA :-(
Trying to see if I can fix it

Comment: Ok, if I had to remove na.rm bit to get the situation where 1 is NA works.
I also remove rows with all questions are NA. Will update this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your data.frame is massive, you can use `apply` on rows (`MARGIN = 1`)

```
df$user_id[apply(X = df[,-1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)]
#[1] 1 3

df[apply(X = df[,-1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1),]
#  user_id q1 q2 q3 q4
#1       1  5  5  5  5
#3       3  2  2  2  2
```

OR

```
df$user_id[Reduce(function(x, y) pmax(x, y, na.rm = TRUE), df[,-1]) ==
               Reduce(function(x, y) pmin(x, y, na.rm = TRUE), df[,-1])]
#[1] 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks d.b. I haven't learnt functions so I'll remember this for future.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with some basic R code.

```
# Generate your data set
df <- data.frame(user_id =c(1,2,3,4),
                 q1 = c(5,4,2,5),
                 q2 = c(5,3,2,4),
                 q3 = c(5,5,2, NA),
                 q4 = c(5,6,2,4))

# populate the vector with a loop
test <- character(0)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
# check if the sum of the values is equal to the sum of the last value 
# repeated. This can only be true if all values are the same
  if(sum(df[i,2:5], na.rm = TRUE) - sum(rep(df[i,5],4)) == 0){
    test[i] <- "equal"
  } else{
    test[i] <- "not_equal"
  }

}

# finally attach the vector as a column to your data frame
df$test <- test
```